# Laravel Spark installation issue

Tags: php, installation, laravel-spark

I am stuck in laravel-spark installation. Below is the error coming whenever I am trying to install via composer.

> Installing laravel/spark-aurelius (v6.0.11): Downloading (failed)    Failed to download laravel/spark-aurelius from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/laravel/spark-aurelius/zipball/9e96a2a3aa26801d141ebc40a2d92533dc6f926d" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
>       Now trying to download from a source

Here are complete details in a screenshot:

[image]

Also, the token is successfully authenticated now the below error comes.

> [RuntimeException]
>     Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout "https://***:***@github.com/laravel/spark-aurelius.git" "D:\Ampps\www\upt
>     \vendor\laravel\spark-aurelius" && cd /D "D:\Ampps\www\upt\vendor\laravel\spark-aurelius" && git remote add compose
>     r "https://***:***@github.com/laravel/spark-aurelius.git" && git fetch composer
>     Cloning into 'D:\Ampps\www\upt\vendor\laravel\spark-aurelius'...
>     remote: Repository not found.
>     fatal: repository 'https://***:***@github.com/laravel/spark-aurelius.git/' not found

Comment: You should do a  search for that error message. That is not an open repository, and you need to request access to the private repo in some manner.

Comment: @jav that issue is fixed could you review the question. I got another error.

Comment: The error seems very clear: you do not have an auth token required to get access to this private repo. You need to show that this is not the case. (It's unclear why you are showing what might be a solved error, otherwise.) Are those strange Github URLs expected? What other research have you done?

Comment: More hints: https://github.com/laravel/docs/issues/3544

Comment: already check this out bro... He has tutorial for spark 1.0 not for the 6.0

Comment: How is anyone supposed to know what you've tried and what you've researched? Mind-reading is not one of the services here. You have a few hints you can chase down: those github URLs are not right, and these repos depend on Github auth magic more than just getting a token.

Comment: I am not trying but I read the documentation and then tell you I got the point now. https://twitter.com/laravelphp/status/723164661772890112?lang=en from this URL. That was what I missing.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @HassanRaza this was in the first link I provided.

Comment: @halfer when we are trying to understand something new and we tried to find the solution but we could not then we have a hope that we will put our case to stackoverflow and the volunteers will help us... What type of way we should follow to get the answer could you tell me that?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment. Obviously, you are invited to ask for help here - that is the point of the site. However, I think it is important not to beg and plead, as my link explains. Most readers believe this ought to go without saying.

Comment: Humbleness is not begging my brother... I think you consider me wrong... I choose that wording because I have a sequence to learn thing everyone wishes they got the answer as earlier as possible. And maybe I am new to StackOverflow and I am learning from you guys... Hope you don't mind.

Comment: My brother, "urgent" is not humble. It is a demand in the form of "serve me immediately" or "deal with my problem first". It is the opposite of humble. Hope this helps!

Comment: I will take care next time. But I don't know about that. Thank you for pointing my mistake...